# Using special characters to call functions PHP

Tags: php

Alright so I've been struggling a bit, Is it possible to create something like this

```
public function @_open($test_string) {
    echo $test_string;
}
```

Basically, is there any way to use special characters inside function names?

At the moment I've done that and I've got

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting identifier

Comment: From [the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php), *A valid function name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores*

Comment: Yeah, I know about that, Im just wondering is there any work around to use special characters as part of it?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Just working around with my buddy, we are trying to re-create some parts of our dynamic functions, this would significantly improve our control over them. Its extremly hard to explain but all in all, its just that would make our life easier in a way

Comment: You could create an associative array whose keys are the names with special characters, and values are function objects.

Comment: How were you planning on calling a function whose name begins with `@`? When you put `@` at the beginning of a function call, that means to suppress errors, it won't be treated as part of the name.

Comment: I love the array idea, thanks for that one, that will resolve it! Much love brother!

Answer (score 0):

No. Only letters, numbers, and underscores may be used in a function name.